# Is it possible to parse a String into a Binary value?

Tags: arduino, binary, arduino-uno

Hi and thanks in advance for any answers.

I wanted to know if there is a way to convert a string (for example str = "B10010"), to the same binary value (eg. int = B10010).

I wanna clarify that I wanna do this because it would be way easier to go back and forth between a charArray and string to change the one digit in the binary value, so if there is a better to do that (and I feel like there should be) I would love to know :)

Comment: What you need to learn is [bit manipulation](https://medium.com/@livajorge7/a-beginners-guide-to-bit-manipulation-understanding-the-basics-and-common-techniques-b4e725b448eb) instead of converting between char array and string for changing a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert a string to a binary:

```
byte getByteFromString(char* str){
    // Don't accept strings less than 8 long
    if(strlen(str) < 8) return;
    byte retval;
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++){
       // shift over what's there
       retval = retval << 1;
       if(str[i] == 1){
          retval |= 1;
       }
    }
    return retval;
}
```

> That answers your question, but I also saw this: I wanna clarify that
> I wanna do this because it would be way easier to go back and forth
> between a charArray and string to change the one digit in the binary
> value, so if there is a better to do that (and I feel like there
> should be) I would love to know :)

and I have to say no, this is a crazy way to do it.  It is WAY easier to just work with binary values.

To set a bit in a binary value, OR with a byte with only that bit.

if bit is 0-7 marking the bit you want to set

```
value = value | (1 << bit);
```

To clear a bit, AND with a byte with only that bit cleared

```
value = value & ~(1<<bit);
```

Here is some more to read:
https://docs.arduino.cc/learn/programming/bit-math